# How to sort multiple times by different cols in SQL？

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark-sql, hive

I want to sort multiple times by different cols in SQL.

Here is the code:

```
set d1 = '${zdt.addDay(-1).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set d30 = '${zdt.addDay(-30).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set d180 = '${zdt.addDay(-180).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set topN = 10;

with item_stats_query_topN as (
    select *
        , row_number() over(partition by code order by expo_d1 desc) as rk_1
        , row_number() over(partition by code order by expo_d30 desc) as rk_30
        , row_number() over(partition by code order by expo_d180 desc) as rk_180
    from (
        select 
            code, coalesce(query, '__all__') as query

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d1
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d1
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d1

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d30
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d30
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d30

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d180
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d180
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d180

        from db.table
        group by code, query
        grouping sets((code), (code, query))
    )
    having rk_1 <= ${query_topN} 
        or rk_30 <= ${query_topN} 
        or rk_180 <= ${query_topN}
)

-- insert overwrite
select code
    , collect_list(if(rk_1 <= ${query_topN}, concat_ws(':', query, expo_d1, clk_d1, avg_dr_d1), null)) as arr_d1
    , collect_list(if(rk_30 <= ${query_topN}, concat_ws(':', query, expo_d30, clk_d30, avg_dr_d30), null)) as arr_d30
    , collect_list(if(rk_180 <= ${query_topN}, concat_ws(':', query, expo_d180, clk_d180, avg_dr_d180), null)) as arr_d180
from item_stats_query_topN
group by code
```

The above code use 3 times windows function `row_number() over(partition by code order by xxx desc)`, and use another `group by code` at final output. Because this SQL takes a lot of time, I want to merge these four `partition/group by code`.

Here is something I want to achieve:

```
set d1 = '${zdt.addDay(-1).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set d30 = '${zdt.addDay(-30).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set d180 = '${zdt.addDay(-180).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}';
set topN = 10;

with item_stats_query_topN as (
    select collect_list(if(row_number() over(order by expo_d1 desc) < ${topN}
            , concat_ws(':', query, expo_d1, clk_d1, avg_dr_d1), null)) as arr_d1
        , collect_list(if(row_number() over(order by expo_d30 desc) < ${topN}
            , concat_ws(':', query, expo_d30, clk_d30, avg_dr_d30), null)) as arr_d30
        , collect_list(if(row_number() over(order by expo_d180 desc) < ${topN}
            , concat_ws(':', query, expo_d180, clk_d180, avg_dr_d180), null)) as arr_d180
    from (
        select 
            code, coalesce(query, '__all__') as query

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d1
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d1
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d1}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d1

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d30
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d30
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d30}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d30

            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180}, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as expo_d180
            , coalesce(count(distinct if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180} and clicked = 1, concat_ws('_', id, vid, code), null)), 0) as clk_d180
            , coalesce(avg(if(d <= ${d1} and d >= ${d180}, dr, null)), 0) as avg_dr_d180

        from db.table
        group by code, query
        grouping sets((code), (code, query))
    )
    group by code
)

-- insert overwrite
select *
from item_stats_query_topN
```

But I got an error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use a window function inside an aggregate function. Please use the inner window function in a sub-query.`

Is there any way to achieve this, or to optimize the running time of this sql?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can use UDF to achieve this, is there some way else?